# php $_GET loses value after submitting form, so i m failing to update a database table using it

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, get

This is the page where im trying to update the database page

everything is correct except for the part that loses the value in the $_get after submitting the form initially its there but it gets lost

```
$active_id=$_GET['client_id'];



 $query = "UPDATE clients SET name='$updatedName1',surname = '$updatedSurname', tel1='$updatedTel1', tel2='$updatedTel2', id_num='$updatedTel2', 
                                         address='$updatedAddress1' WHERE client_id = '$active_id' ";
```

this is the page where i get the value from,

```
 if ( $name != ''){
                  echo "<tr>", "<td>", "<a  href=\"display_row.php?client_id=$id\">",$id_num, "   " ,$name ,"    ",$surname,"</a>","</td>","</tr>";

echo "<form method ='POST' name = 'update' action='display_row.php'>";
            echo "</br>";
            echo "</br>";
            echo  "<th style='color:green' >name</th><th style='color:green'>surname</th>"; 
            echo  "<tr >","<td>","<input type ='text'  name ='surname' value ='$Fname'>","<td>","<input type ='text' name ='name' value ='$Fsurname'>","</td>","</tr>";
            echo "</table>";
            echo  "</br>";
            echo  "</br>";
            echo "<table>";
            echo  "<th style='color:green' >Telephone1</th><th style='color:green'>Telephone2</th>"; 
            echo  "<tr >","<td>","<input type ='text'  name ='tel1' value ='$Ftel1'  >","<td>","<input type ='text' name ='tel2' value ='$Ftel2'>","</td>","</tr>";
            echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>","<td>","<label style='color:green'>Id No: ","</td>","</tr>", "<tr>","<td>","<input type ='text' name ='id_num' value ='$Fid_num' >","</td>","</tr>","</br>","</br>";
            echo "<tr>","<td>","<label style='color:green'>Address: " ,"</td>","</tr>", "<tr>","<td>", "<input type ='text' name ='address' value ='$Faddress' >","</td>","</tr>","</br>","</br>";
            echo "</table>","</br>","</br>";
            echo "<input type ='submit'  style='color:green;width:120;height:60;border-radius: 25px;' name= 'go' value ='Update'>";
            echo "</br>";
            echo "</br>";
            echo "</br>";
           echo "</form>";
```

Comment: Where is the form/url call submitting this? Can you add that to the post?

Comment: @Norbert van Nobelen are you referring the code behind my post button or the complete form

Comment: With a get you can test with just an URL or with a form. So the form or the url is the minimum. If you use a form: Post the form please.

Comment: ? @NorbertvanNobelen the url is in his post already: `display_row.php?client_id=$id`

Comment: Where are you accessing $_GET? The variable will only be accessible via the page you make the request to, unless you store the result elsewhere.

Comment: @Norbert van Nobelen i have edited my original post to include the form please review and assist thanks

Comment: @Martyn Shutt im getting the variable from a previous page and then i process the form on the next page, but after submitting the form the value is lost before updating the database. i need the value because is it is the id that i m using to update the database with

Comment: @anchor I understand. Genhis' answer should solve your problem. When you post a form, the url becomes whatever is in your form action, and when you go to check $_GET, it's no longer there, because it's no longer in the last url processed by the server.

Answer (score 3):

There are two possible solutions:

1. Insert your `GET` values into `action`

   ```
    <form action='<your_action>&client_id=<?=$_GET["client_id"]?>'>
   ```
2. Use hidden `input` for `GET` values and then use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`

   ```
    <input type='hidden' name='client_id' value='<?=$_GET["client_id"]?>'>
   ```

Comment: `@Genhis i got your valuable suggestion.. is this what you ,Thanks 
<form action='<POST&client_id=<?=$_GET["client_id"]?>'>``